# Если я возьму исходники qtnetwork и скопирую их в свой проект, соберется ли оно статично в мой ехе?

Tags: qt

Если я возьму исходники qtnetwork  и скопирую их в свой проект, соберется ли qtnetwork статично в мой ехе?

Comment: если вам нужна статическая сборка qt так и пишите. Отдельно использовать сырцы qtnetwork не получится они как и другие зависят от базовых вещей qt. Вы можете собрать себе комплект qt где будет только нужный вам модуль.

Comment: мне нужен статичный кьют, но с динамической ssl

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю что исходники кьют не полные, и в их снове лежат базовые бинарные либы?